# Projection - mapping two properties into one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, automapper

I'm trying to create a projection mapping with `Automapper 3.3.0` which maps two properties from my entity into one property in the DTO.

For Example:

```
public class Entity
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}

public class DTO
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
```

So I create a projection like this one:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, DTO>()
.ForMember(
    d => d.Start, map => map.MapFrom(e => e.StartDate.Add(e.StartTime.TimeOfDay))
)
```

The problem is, that this one creates a query against our MSSQL database which throws a `NotSupportedException` which says that LINQ to Entities doesn't know the method `DateTime.Add()`.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: LINQ to Entities doesn't like `DateTime.Add()` since it has absolutely no idea how to translate that into a SQL query, which is what LINQ to Entities is made for. You're also going to have problems with `TimeOfDay`, since that's not supported either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've managed to fix this by creating a fake method which "calls" a function in our database as this one is called by LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't know how to handle this, so I would create a property on the destination type to do the calculation:

```
public class Entity
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}

public class DTO
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get { return StartDate.Add(StartTime.TimeOfDay); } }
}
```

Comment: This solution also came to my mind, but my colleague told me that this won't work as the filtering and sorting in our DataTables need the fields in the entity. So if I try to sort or filter by `Start` I'll get an exception as the application can not resolve the underlying entity/properties.

Comment: Then your question should be "How do I combine a date and time that are in separate fields in Entity Framework". AutoMapper merely passes your expressions down to the query provider. If your query provider doesn't support that expression, it's up to you to figure out alternatives at that layer.